# Is there any toolkit , reference or library files for touchscreen windows form application in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, touch

I'm creating simple application for desktop application in which user can give input by pen/stylus as their signature. Is there any reference in .net for this features?

Comment: Pretty unclear, I suppose you are looking for the Microsoft.Ink namespace.

Comment: Actually i am new to touchscreen application. 
My requirement are:
User can give the input as digital signature from pen/stylus. i need to manipulate that input into image. I'm able to do this making own canvas and mouse event in win-form in vb.net. How can i implement it into the touchscreen PC/Tablets. So i'm looking for the references used to such touch application. I check Microsoft.Ink namespace but i don't have it. Do i have to install any toolkit for this? I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

I rather found this class/namespace: System.Windows.Input.Stylus (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604577.aspx). Although it helps capturing stylus movements and system gestures, it is not clear how to make your own gestures.

Serge

Comment: I went through the link but I'm having application in winform. This System.Windows.Input.Stylus class/namespace is only available in WPF.

Comment: @s3niya - You should still be able to use it.  Just add a reference to the appropriate assembly and import the correct namespace.  If you find you need a WPF control for it, you can use ElementHost to host a WPF user control in your winforms app.